# Prolog HTTP Dispatch handle encapsulation

Tags: http, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm creating a program in Prolog using a HTTP server to make requests...

I'm want to encapsulate the code in a way I can reuse it and have the http stuff in one module, my "controller" to handle requests in another module, etc.

I started having problems with the http dispatch handler registration:

```
:- http_handler('/test', foobar, []).
```

Is it possible to have something like this:

```
register_handler(path, callback) :-
    http_handler(path, callback, []).
```

I tried using that but I got a error must likely due to the "callback" parameter. Also, the callback predicate is defined in a different module so I used:

```
:-consult(api_controller).
```

**[EDIT]**

*server.pl*

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

:- use_module(api_controller).

:- http_handler('/test', foo, []).  

server(Port):-http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).
```

*api_controller.pl*

```
foo(_request) :-
    format('Content-type: text/plain~n~n'),
    format('Hello world!~n').
```

*Error*:

```
http_dispatch:call_action/2: Undefined procedure: foo/1
```

Answer (score 2):

`http_handler/3` is a **directive**, and you can place such directives in other files and then use `include/1` to load them.

In addition, you can have **total control** over the HTTP dispatch by installing a *generic handler* as follows:

```
:- http_handler(/, handle_request, [prefix]).
```

Note the `prefix` option.

Then, you supply a suitable `handle_request/1`, for example like this:

```
handle_request(Request) :-
        debug(my_dispatch, "~q\n", [Request]),
        memberchk(path(Path0), Request),
        atom_concat(., Path0, Path1),
        http_safe_file(Path1, []),
        absolute_file_name(Path1, Path),
        (   reply_file(Path0, File) -> http_reply_file(File, [unsafe(true)], Request)
        ;   redirect(Path0, Other)  -> http_redirect(moved, Other, Request)
        ;   see_other(Path0, Other) -> http_redirect(see_other, Other, Request)
        ;   hidden_file(Path0)      -> http_404([], Request)
        ;   exists_file(Path)       -> http_reply_file(Path, [unsafe(true)], Request)
        ;   ...
        ).
```

In this example, the following predicates are meant to be supplied by *you* to tailor the server to your exact use cases:

- `reply_file(Path, File)`: Send contents `File` in response to request `Path`.
- `redirect(Path0, Path)`: Redirect to `Path` in response to `Path0`.
- `see_other/2`: Meaning left as an exercise.
- `hidden_file/1`: Meaning left as an exercise.

These rules can be defined elsewhere, and you can include these files with the directive:

```
:- include(other_source).
```

A related directive you should check out is `multifile/1`.

I leave figuring out the precise libraries you need for the above to work as an exercise. A starting point:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_server_files)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_files)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_header)).
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I think I understood!

Comment: See my post plz. Currently, you are **not** using `include/1`, but `use_module/1`, you are **not** using `/`, but `/test`, you are **not** using the `prefix` option, but `[]`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: OK! Check out the differences between `use_module/1` and `include/1`. If you are going for modules, you need a corresponding `module/2` directive in the module, and *export* the predicates you need. Using `include/1` may be somewhat easier at the beginning, so consider starting with that. In the way I suggest above, you place `handle_request/1` in the **same** source file as the `http_handler/3` directive, and the other predicates I mention  can be located in different files, and also be spread across further files. Overall, this should give you the flexibility you want.